# Как или чем спарсить динамический текст

Tags: selenium, bs4, lxml, web-scraping

Пытаюсь написать парсер на языке python при помощи Scrapy.

Вот сайт https://1wtuer.top/casino/play/1play_1play_luckyjet

Нужно как то считывать числа которые выпадают, в одном из классов, и по возможности записывать для дальнейшего анализа.
При запросе через response.xpath ничего хорошего он не выдает

Возможно тут нужна другая библиотека? Может ли кто что-то посоветовать?

UPD: Итак я стал близок к получнию данных с этого сайта, но что то все равно идет не так...
Я понял что request или bs4 мне кажется не помогут в этом деле, и я перешел на selenium.
В коде по первой ссылке я нашел еще один сайт с тестовым режимом этой игры.
И снова незадача. Задавая для селена By.ID 'root' он находит и выводит мне элемент. Если же я беру следующий для поиска элемент, он выводит мне no "such element: Unable to locate element: ..."
Пробовал через полную строку XPATH, через class, tag_name, но все тщетно...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://lucky-jet-b.1play.one/?exitUrl=null&language=ru&b=demo"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(20)

id_mobile = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'root')
#roots= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mobile"]/div[2]')

print(id_mobile)
#print(roots)

driver.close()
```

UPD: Вопрос решен,все успешно сделано.
Я тут в первые, нужно ли закрывать как то данный топик?

Comment: Приведите ваш код, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться тем, кто захочет помочь :)

Comment: готово, можете посмотреть

Comment: Можешь показать как ты решил данную проблему

Comment: Я решил забить на селен, и сделать парсер на playwright. он легче как мне показалось и удобнее